# How to limit execution of stage in gitlab-ci.yml to some hours?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci.yml

I have multiple stages in gitlab-ci.yml. I want to limit for example deploy to production stage that can be executed only between 8am and 16pm.
Is this "if" statement in stage or it can be solved some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup [deployment freezes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/index.html#prevent-unintentional-releases-by-setting-a-deploy-freeze) to do this.

For example, you can setup your CI YAML like so using `rules:` (you can also check for the freeze in your script, if you want):

```yaml
deploy_to_production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - deploy_to_prod.sh
  rules:
    - if: $CI_DEPLOY_FREEZE == null  # only run when there is no deploy freeze
```

For the effect you stated, you can then configure the deployment freezes with the following parameters:

Freeze start: `0 16 * * *` # start freeze at 16:00, preventing deployments after 4:00PM
Freeze end: `0 8 * * *`  # end this freeze at 8AM (allowing deployments after 8AM)
Timezone: `<your timezone>`

There is no particular way to apply this to a *stage* you'll have to setup `rules:` (or equivalent script steps) for each job you want to not run during the freeze.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in complement of the deploy freeze, [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#display-message-when-deploy-freeze-is-active) (May 2023) now brings:

> ### Display message when deploy freeze is active
>
> GitLab now shows you a message on the Environments page when a deploy freeze is in effect. This helps ensure your team is aware of when freezes occur, and when deployments are not allowed.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/index.html#prevent-unintentional-releases-by-setting-a-deploy-freeze) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/212460).

That way, your team is aware of the restriction you have put in place through cron syntax:

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/img/deploy_freeze_v14_3.png]